# Only 3 apps on my Office 365 E3 - evaluation account

Tags: office365

Dont know if this is the right forum, but MS support sure isnt,m spent almost 2 hours in queues of different kinds, no result.

I have signed up for a E3 (business/enterprice) evaluation account, but when I get to the start page I only see 3 apps/tiles (security, store and admin)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llZOu.jpg)

I know that Im supposed to see more apps, like word, excel...

*(Important detail: I might have gotten an error message after the last step, saying "something got wrong", but could still log in. Actually I cant really remember, since I did the sign-up numerous of times with different results, some of them "seemed" to succeed)*

Answer (score 0):

< rant >

After 8 calls/recalls, numerous re-connections to all departments on MS except the techical, waiting to crappy jazz music with terrible sound quality, talking to monotonous script reading dummies trying to explain that MS´s only way to get to technical support didnt work, a sales person gave me the solution from somthing he picked up somewhere :)

< / rant>

**Do the sign-up in "private mode"** (using IE11)...Now, what is "private mode" you might ask out loud if you manager is reading this with you. Dont play innocent with me young man! "Private mode" is where MS products sometimes works!